# Inserting a file into a folder

Tags: applescript

I can copy the file using AppleScript.

But how can I use it to paste the copied file to another folder?

I couldn't find the right operator or similar question.

```
tell application "Finder" to set the clipboard to (POSIX file "/Users/bgbg/Library/Messages/chat.db")
```

Comment: Why do you need to _paste_ it, why can't you just copy it to where you want it?

Comment: The folder I'm trying to copy the file to is on a volume that has the read-Only attribute. And there is no way to change that. At the same time, the folder itself gives me all possible actions with it. 
When i try to use "cp" through the terminal, nothing happens. 
I used shutil from Python-it works, but some files that I need to insert into this folder do not open for reading, in consequence of which Python can not copy them. 
If I manually copy-paste to a folder, then everything is fine.

Comment: Now I'm using a simulated keystroke, via `key code 9 using command down`. This works, but I would like to find a better solution.

Comment: I'm mentioning this because of the way you've phrased this question... In MacOS, the keyboard 'copy' and 'paste' commands (e.g., the pasteboard)  don't work on files the way they do in Windows. The Finder has separated methods for moving or copying a file, both in the GUI and in AppleScript. If you set the clipboard to a file, I don't think you'll get the result you want — it may just copy the file name — and paste will not make a new copy of the file. Does this apply to your question?

Comment: @Ted Wrigley, e.g. `tell application "Finder" to set the clipboard to (POSIX file "/Users/bgbg/Library/Messages/chat.db")` actually puts the `chat.db` _file on the _clipboard_, however so does e.g. `set the clipboard to (POSIX file "/Users/bgbg/Library/Messages/chat.db")` and this is what should be used as **AppleScript** doesn't need **Finder** to use `the clipboard` and it also can be pasted as a actual file afterwards.

Comment: @user3439894: huh, didn't know that.  But it still strikes me as silly, when we can just move the file using System Events.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley, He doesn't want to _move_ the file. I'd suggest you reread his first comment to my first comment.

Comment: JohnTit, Since you obviously have a method that works, using **System Events** to **⌘V**, I'm not going to waste much though on this unless you can elaborate on the _filesystem_ state and conditions so testing can be done on my side, assuming I can replicate the same _filesystem_ state and conditions you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208201/discussion-between-ted-wrigley-and-user3439894).

Answer (score 1):

It definitely seems odd to me to use the clipboard as the variable for copying and moving files or folders and to use the keystroke command to paste a file into a folder.  However, if you are hell-bent on doing things this way, I do believe this following AppleScript code will accomplish what you’re looking to achieve

```
-- Set The Clipboard To A File (This Only Works With A Single File¬
-- Or Folder And Not With A List Of Files Or Folders)

-- set the clipboard to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt ¬
-- "Set The Clipboard To A Single File Or Folder" invisibles false ¬
--  without multiple selections allowed) as POSIX file

set the clipboard to POSIX path of (((path to library folder from user domain as text) ¬
    & "Messages:chat.db") as alias) as POSIX file

set destinationFolder to (choose folder with prompt ¬
    "Choose Your Destinations Folder" with invisibles)

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat until frontmost
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    reveal destinationFolder
end tell

delay 1

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using {command down}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Finder"` _block_ when you can eliminate that entire `tell` _block_ and simply use `activate application "Finder"` after `tell application "Finder" to reveal destinationFolder`? It sure seems like unnecessary _code_ and no real need to talk to **Finder** through **System Events** when you can talk to **Finder** directly in this case.

Comment: For reasons which I have not been able to pinpoint yet, for some reason the `activate` command in Finder … on my system… does not always bring Finder to the foreground. In fact on my system, it fails at least 50% of the time.  The System Events block  , for me, proves to work 100% of the time

Comment: Okay, that understandable that you need to do it for you, but `activate application "Finder"` always works for me and always brings the newly opened **Finder** _window_ to the front and I have a script that doing this sometimes a dozen times a day and without failure. I'd put the expected _code_ not the _code_ you have use because your system is crippled for whatever reason!

Comment: @CJK The `repeat until frontmost` loop in the Finder tell block in my updated code, seems to have solved the issue on my end.

Comment: @wch1zpink `POSIX path of … as text as alias as POSIX file` is a tiny bit overkill.  Try this: **`set the clipboard to "" & (path to library folder from user domain) & "Messages:chat.db" as «class furl»`**